# Converting Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> to ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, readonly-collection

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
public enum Role { Role1, Role2, Role3, }
public enum Action { Action1, Action2, Action3, }

var dictionary = new Dictionary<Role, List<Action>>();

dictionary.Add(RoleType.Role1, new Action [] { Action.Action1, Action.Action2 }.ToList());
```

Now I want to be able to construct a read-only dictionary whose value type is also read-only as follows:

```
var readOnlyDictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<Role, ReadOnlyCollection<Action>>(dictionary);
```

The last line obviously causes a compile-time error due to the differences in `TValue` types.

Using a `List<TValue>` is also necessary since the original dictionary is programatically populated from an external source.

Is there an easy way to perform this conversion?

Comment: Did you know that collections like lists can be also initialized using collection initializers? ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Yes I did. But I need to construct the read-only collections at runtime.

Comment: No, I was suggesting this because you build a list from an array...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: My bad. That is misleading indeed.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I meant misleading in context of the question. The values I'll be getting at runtime so cannot initialize using arrays or initializers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Converting a Dictionary to a ReadOnlyDictionary is as simple as passing the regular dictionary as a parameter to the constructor of ReadOnlyDictionary:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<K, V>();

var myReadOnlyDict = new ReadOnlyDictionary<K, V>(myDictionary);
```

Comment: How is this one marked as correct answer??? This doesn't answer the part where the lists in the read-only dictionary are read-only collections too.

Answer (score 11):

One possibility (probably suboptimal for large collections) would be to construct a new `Dictionary` object of the desired type (using the [Enumerable.ToDictionary overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx)) and use the [List.AsReadOnly() extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var readOnlyDictionary = 
    new ReadOnlyDictionary<Role, ReadOnlyCollection<Action>>
        (dictionary.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.AsReadOnly()));
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. The ToDictionary transformation works great.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly 5 years later, here is a simple solution that adapts a dictionary, correctly handling covariance of the value's type.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a <see cref="AsReadOnly{TKey, TValue, TReadOnlyValue}(IDictionary{TKey, TValue})"/>
/// method on any generic dictionary.
/// </summary>
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    class ReadOnlyDictionaryWrapper<TKey, TValue, TReadOnlyValue> : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TReadOnlyValue>
            where TValue : TReadOnlyValue
            where TKey : notnull
    {
        private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

        public ReadOnlyDictionaryWrapper( IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary )
        {
            if( dictionary == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(dictionary) );
            _dictionary = dictionary;
        }
        public bool ContainsKey( TKey key ) => _dictionary.ContainsKey( key );

        public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys => _dictionary.Keys;

        public bool TryGetValue( TKey key, [MaybeNullWhen( false )]out TReadOnlyValue value )
        {
            var r = _dictionary.TryGetValue( key, out var v );
            value = v!;
            return r;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TReadOnlyValue> Values => _dictionary.Values.Cast<TReadOnlyValue>();

        public TReadOnlyValue this[TKey key] => _dictionary[key];

        public int Count => _dictionary.Count;

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TReadOnlyValue>> GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.Select( x => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TReadOnlyValue>( x.Key, x.Value ) ).GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a wrapper on a dictionary that adapts the type of the values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The dictionary key.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The dictionary value.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TReadOnlyValue">The base type of the <typeparamref name="TValue"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">This dictionary.</param>
    /// <returns>A dictionary where values are a base type of this dictionary.</returns>
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TReadOnlyValue> AsReadOnly<TKey, TValue, TReadOnlyValue>( this IDictionary<TKey,TValue> @this )
        where TValue : TReadOnlyValue
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        return new ReadOnlyDictionaryWrapper<TKey, TValue, TReadOnlyValue>( @this );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. And the usage goes like this (for my case):  

public class SettlementResources
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<Building, IReadOnlyDictionary<ResourceType, int>> BuildingStorage { get; }

    readonly Dictionary<Building, Dictionary<ResourceType, int>> BuildingStorage_ = new();

    SettlementResources()
    {
        BuildingStorage = BuildingStorage_.AsReadOnly<Building, Dictionary<ResourceType, int>, IReadOnlyDictionary<ResourceType, int>>();
    }
}